# Manage data sets in Python, for usage with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make some datasets for matplotlib, out of excel spreadsheet.

So far I have extracted data from the spreadsheet and put everything in a dictionary of lists; so I have all the data related to each experiment, in its own structure.

Although I am having problems to feed this data to matplotlib; since I have various fields and would like to get data to compare results from different experiments.

Is there a basic structure used to display data in matplotlib? Something that I can use as example to build my own. I usually do data gathering and aggregation on excel spreadsheet, but now I would like to learn how to do it properly in Python, so I can save time to do all the calculations every time I get a spreadsheet with the results.

This is the type of data structure that I did create :

```
Experiment 1
    ID
    compound 1:
    compound 2:
    machine:
    reagent
    val1
    val2
    val3
    val4

    ID
    compound 1:
    compound 2:
    machine:
    reagent
    val1
    val2
    val3
    val4

Experiment 2

    ID
    compound 1:
    compound 2:
    machine:
    reagent
    val1
    val2
    val3
    val4

    ID
    compound 1:
    compound 2:
    machine:
    reagent
    val1
    val2
    val3
    val4

...
experiment N
```

Each experiment may have one or more "takes", identified with ID; the values for the compounds, machine and reagents are in a list of possible choices, so there may be different ID in the same experiment, using one or more common entry, so the unique values are only the val from 1 to 4.

Example:

```
Experiment collisionA
    ID 001
    compound 1: Hg
    compound 2: Cl
    machine: SPF
    reagent: CH3COOH
    val1 0.12
    val2 0.22
    val3 0.14
    val4 1

    ID 002
    compound 1: Fe
    compound 2: Cl
    machine: SPF
    reagent CH4
    val1 0.23
    val2 0.4
    val3 0.42
    val4 0.98

Experiment collisionB

    ID 001
    compound 1: Fe
    compound 2: Cl
    machine: MIC
    reagent NaCl
    val1 0.2
    val2 0.15
    val3 0.3
    val4 0.99

...
```

I would like to calculate for example, for experiment 1, the values of val2, for each ID, so I can graph it, then graph val1 for example, in relation to compound 1 and so on.

It is clear that my structure does not work, since it is very complicate to extrapolate any data that require more than one filter, so I thought that there must be something to follow, to get data in a way that it is easy to manage and display.

I did check some database books but nothing did strike me, as useful, so before going for the tangent, I thought would be good to ask and see if any of you, accustomed to work with data, could give me some hints to start.

Comment: Creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example is generally a good idea.  However, the answer you are looking for is [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)  Pandas can take your data directly out of the excal sheets, and manipulate and then plot it.  pandas is also fairly well supported right here on SO, **IF** questions about it are well structured.  It does have a bit of a learning curve, but good tools are often like that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; never heard of pandas, but it seems like the right answer, instead of me re-inventing the wheel and managing all the data on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Pandas is definitely an option. I just want to mention that python ships with [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) and therby provides an easy database interface. I used this for a similar task in the past and it's working great.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of sqlite, which is what I did use in the past for my data needs; but I was looking for something that is not tied to a db system. I get the excel files from the lab team, if there was a will to put this data in a db, sqlite would be the way to go, but at this point, since I just read the excel files once to get data, I think that Pandas may be the most efficient way. So far it doesn't look that hard; and it is similar enough to standard DB usage, to make you feel decently comfortable :)